# Circle touching 2 sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry

The centre of a circle inside a triangle is at a distance of 625 units from each of the vertices of the triangle. If the diameter of the circle is 350 units and the circle is touching only two sides of the triangle, find the area of the triangle.
I am not able to solve this question. Help.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @daOnlyBG I just know that the circumradius is 625 units. I have been able to find the length of the tangent from the common vertex of the two sides touching the circle. That's about it.

Comment: You should find that the triangle is isosceles, and that you can find the two equal sides. The circle also makes it easy to calculate the trigonometric ratios for the angle between the sides - and you can calculate the area from the two sides and the ratios for the angle between them.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yupp. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Figure]

Here is how you could construct this situation: You could start by drawing the circle, with radius $\frac{350}2=175$ around any point. Then draw a larger circle with radius $625$ around that same center. All three corners must lie on the larger circles, and two edges must be tangents to the smaller one. So pick an arbitrary point $A$ on the larger circle, draw tangents to the smaller circle, and the points where these tangents intersect the larger circle are the points $B$ and $C$.

But I take it that you want to know the number exactly, not measure some construction. So think about the image you obtained. For reasons of symmetry, $AE=EC$. Since you know $AF$ and you know $FE$ and since $\angle AEF=90°$, you can compute $AE$ and therefore $AC$.

$$AC=2\sqrt{625^2-175^2}$$

Furthermore, if you define $\alpha=\angle FAE$ then you know $\sin\alpha=\frac{175}{625}=\frac7{25}$. From that you can deduce the vector from $A$ to $C$:

$$\overrightarrow{AC}=AC\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha\\\sin\alpha\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}AG\\GC\end{pmatrix}$$

From that you get the area of the triangle as

$$ 2\cdot\frac12\cdot AG\cdot GC = AC^2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha
= 4\left(625^2-175^2\right)\frac{175}{625}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{175}{625}\right)^2}
= 387072 $$

Comment: The *diameter* is $350$, not the radius.